# Send email to Tenant admin in normal user session

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have the need to send a email to a admin moderator (Tenant admin).
How do I obtain the admin email through a normal user session?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in application service

```
using (UnitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
{
            var adminUser = _userManager
                .AbpStore
                .UserRepository
                .GetAll()
                .Single(x => x.UserName == AbpUserBase.AdminUserName && x.TenantId == AbpSession.TenantId);


            SendEmailTo(adminUser.EmailAddress);
}
```

Comment: Probably not needed to disable soft delete since Admin user can not be deleted. Even if it's deleted, is it true to trust email of a deleted user or send emails to a deleted user?